# How can I upload my app's database file in android development?

Tags: android

I made application for merchants to store information about their clients in sqlite database
the problem is , I want my app to store this database file into google drive 
How can I do that?

Comment: Please show us code with what you have tried.

Comment: I didn't try any thing , I don't know where to start